# dynamically create button at runtime and store , retrieve it permenantly in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have create button dynamically at run time.
but when i close and reopen those buttons will be gone.
how it store permanently dynamically created buttons and other controls.

Dynamically create control button code is:

```
    int loc=150;
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    CreateDynamicButton();
    }

        private void CreateDynamicButton()
        {
            // Create a Button object 
            Button dynamicButton = new Button();

            // Set Button properties
            dynamicButton.Height = 40;
            dynamicButton.Width = 300;
            dynamicButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dynamicButton.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            dynamicButton.Location = new Point(20, loc);
    loc=loc+50;
            dynamicButton.Text = "I am Dynamic Button";
            dynamicButton.Name = "DynamicButton";
            dynamicButton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);

            // Add a Button Click Event handler
            dynamicButton.Click += new EventHandler(DynamicButton_Click);

            // Add Button to the Form. Placement of the Button
            // will be based on the Location and Size of button
            Controls.Add(dynamicButton);            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Button click event handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void DynamicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dynamic button is clicked");
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject=sender;
*****and i change it some color fontsize in propertyGrid1 it will be changed
*****how do i save permanently 
        }
```

please help me how to store all controls permanently(control color,position,name ... )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really, or it would not be dynamic. You need to call the code every time you need the button. You can store it in a file or table if that is what you want.

In your example, there is not much need for the button to be dynamic as far as I can judge. But perhaps it is only intended as an example

Comment: It just a sample but i store the layout and properties of all controls. please any possible way edit using get current property using propertygrid save and load permenantlly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and serialize the whole `Controls` object.

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try 
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, Controls);
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
```

And to deserialize

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
    try 
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Controls = (Control.ControlCollection)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
```